Envoy/emissary: Remote Log protobuf definition is not clear
I need to send proxy logs from emissary to my remote collector as per https://www.getambassador.io/docs/emissary/latest/topics/running/services/log-service
I have collector and client for testing. Everything working fine with my own proto/schema. The only problem is envoy schema/protobuf definition. As per documentation they claim it should be taken from https://github.com/emissary-ingress/emissary/blob/master/api/envoy/service/accesslog/v3/als.proto - i have it but still emissary is sending events in a different format (and my collector does not understand those).
The last proto definition i have tried:
syntax = "proto3";

package envoy.service.accesslog.v3;

import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

option go_package = "./accesslog";

service AccessLogService {
    rpc StreamAccessLogs(StreamAccessLogsRequest) returns (stream StreamAccessLogsResponse);
}

message StreamAccessLogsRequest {
    // The log entries to send
    repeated LogEntry log_entries = 1;
}

message LogEntry {
    // Log data
    string request_id = 1;
    google.protobuf.Struct metadata = 2; // Additional metadata
    google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 3; // Time of the log entry
}

message StreamAccessLogsResponse {
    // Response for access logs
    string status = 1; // e.g., "success" or "failure"
}


Note: everything else is well tested and working fine. I have packet captures with the payload from emissary to collector (unencrypted), but can not extract "protobuf" from that payload....
Any hints/ideas how to move on ? What would be the best way for the server to "discover"/"reverese engineer" client protobuf ? Or maybe it's possible to build it from envoy sources ? (tried multiple solutions but all failed....).
Honestly this go and protobuf is a disaster, not portable solution at all..
Thanks,
